# Can't append object to array of objects in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, api, swifty-json

So I'm trying to access data from an `API` that gives me a `JSON` file with local businesses, I'm using `swiftyJSON` to get the data from the `JSON` file and then checking if they are not nil to the assign them to public variables and then create objects(Venues) from said data. But the problem is that I can't append the objects(Venues) to my Venues Array.

Here is my code:

```
//File Name: ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import QuadratTouch
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UITableViewController{

   //Here I create an empty array of Venue Objects  
   var venuesArr = [Venue]()


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callAPI()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.venuesArr.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.venuesArr[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    func callAPI(){

        let session = Session.sharedSession()
        var parameters = [Parameter.section: "food" ]
        parameters += [Parameter.near:"Massachusetts"]
        parameters += [Parameter.radius:"16093"]
        parameters += [Parameter.limit:"20"]
        let searchTask = session.venues.explore(parameters) {
            (result) -> Void in
            if let response = result.response {
                myJSON = JSON(response)

                let group = myJSON["groups"][0]

                for var i = 0; i < 20;i++ {

                    var items = group["items"][i]
                    var venue = items["venue"]


                    if venue["name"] != nil{
                        venueName = venue["name"].string as String!
                    }

                    if venue["hours"]["status"] != nil{
                        venueHoursStatus = venue["hours"]["status"].string as String!
                    }

                    if venue["hours"]["isOpen"] != nil{
                        venueIsOpen = Bool(venue["hours"]["isOpen"])
                    }

                    let venueRating = venue["rating"].doubleValue

                    if venue["location"]["address"] != nil{
                        venueStreetAddress = venue["location"]["address"].string as String!
                    }

                    if venue["location"]["city"] != nil{
                        venueCity = venue["location"]["city"].string as String!
                    }

                    if  venue["location"]["postalCode"] != nil{
                        venuePostalCode = venue["location"]["postalCode"].string as String!
                    }

                    if venue["location"]["state"] != nil{
                        venueState = venue["location"]["state"].string as String!
                    }

                    if (venue["hasMenu"] != nil){
                        venueHasMenu = Bool(venue["hasMenu"])
                    }

                    if (venue["menu"]["mobileUrl"] != nil){
                        venueMenuURL = venue["menu"]["mobileUrl"].string as String!
                    }


                    let venueObject = Venue(name: venueName, hoursStatus: venueHoursStatus, isOpen: venueIsOpen, streetAddress: venueStreetAddress, city: venueCity, state: venueState, postalCode: venuePostalCode, hasMenu: venueHasMenu, menuURL: venueMenuURL, rating: venueRating)

                    //Here is the PROBLEM ----------
                    self.venuesArr.append(venueObject) //--------> This gets called and stores the objects
                     //Here is the PROBLEM ----------

                }//end of loop

            }
        }
        searchTask.start()


    }




    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is the class definition for Venue

```
//File Name: Venue.swift
import Foundation

public class Venue{

var name: String
var hoursStatus: String
var hasMenu: Bool
var isOpen: Bool
var streetAddress : String
var city : String
var postalCode : String
var state: String
var menuURL:String
var rating: Double


init(name:String, hoursStatus: String, isOpen: Bool, streetAddress : String, city : String, state: String, postalCode : String, hasMenu: Bool, menuURL:String, rating: Double){

    self.name = name
    self.hoursStatus = hoursStatus
    self.hasMenu = hasMenu
    self.isOpen = isOpen
    self.streetAddress = streetAddress
    self.city = city
    self.postalCode = postalCode
    self.state = state
    self.menuURL = menuURL
    self.rating = rating

  }   
}
```

The debugger shows me that the objects are stored, but then when I try to access them, they aren't there anymore. Please help!
image of debugger [image]

Here is my last file that holds some variables:

```
//File Name: Variables.swift
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

//JSON that contains API info
public var myJSON:JSON!

//Venue variables
public var venueName: String!
public var venueHoursStatus: String!
public var venueIsOpen: Bool!
public var venueStreetAddress: String!
public var venueCity: String!
public var venuePostalCode: String!
public var venueState:String!
public var venueHasMenu: Bool!
public var venueMenuURL: String!
```

Comment: The function `callAPI` can't possibly compile.  The variables `venueName`, `venueHoursStatus`, are not declared (with `var`, `let`) anywhere.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that those are public variables that I declared in another file. So that isn't the problem

Comment: Okay.  How do you 'try to access them'?

Comment: EX: I have a file called variables.swift that holds "public var venueHasMenu: Bool!" then I go to my view controller, I fetch the data from an API and set the value of venueHasMenue  = (data from API). Since they are public vars there isn't an specific way to access them, right? PS: I've added the file that holds the variables to my question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I was trying to display the data in the array to a tableView, and then I realized I didn't reload the tableview at the end of `callAPI()` so I simply inserted `self.tableView.reloadData()` and then it worked!

I thought the objects weren't being appended into the array, but they were. The actual problem was that I wasn't reloading the datasource of my tableview.